# Two login forms to be processed by one php script?

Tags: php, html

Have two login forms on one page and two database tables: admin(`user`, `pass`) and customer(`fname`, `laname`, `email`, `user`, `pass`).
One for customer, and one for admin.
Want to process both forms inside `login.php`

How to determine which form was `Submit` button clicked on and access `user` and `pass` fields from both forms inside login.php when trying to store `$_POST` username and password inside respective variables?

Something like this?(goes into login.php):

```
if(//submit button in customer form was clicked){
$user=$_POST['customer_login']['user'];
$pass=$_POST['customer_login']['pass'];
}else{
//admin submit button was clicked
$user=$_POST['admin_login']['user'];
$pass=$_POST['admin_login']['pass'];
}
```

Form(HTML):

```
<form name="customer_login" method="post" action="login.php">
    <h3>Customer:</h3>
    Username: <input type="text" id="user" name="user"><br>
    Password: <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Sign in">
</form>  

<form name="admin_login" method="post" action="login.php">
    <h3>Admin:</h3>
    Username: <input type="text" id="user" name="user"><br>
    Password: <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Sign in">
</form>
```

Comment: You can only process one form at a time.

Comment: That's what I want to do. You either login as admin or customer. Not both at the same time. Just need to figure out how to which form was submitted and process it(one).

Comment: @GrantThomas; "one resource - one request" at one time, yes. Same as requesting on one browser e.g: `GET /user/id/1`. Excepting e.g: `Ajax.get("/user/id/1"); Ajax.get("/user/id/2"); ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Give the submit buttons unique names and/or identifiers and check which is set. From memory, that should work, but otherwise you could use a hidden field per form to indicate a predefined value you know, knowing this value you can process the appropriate data.

Comment: for example, set one submit button to `<input type="submit" name="customer_submit" value="Sign In" />` and the other to `<input type="submit" name="admin_submit" value="Sign In" />`. In your php script listen for `$_POST['customer_submit']` and `$_POST['admin_submit']` and process as necessary.

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King
By listen you mean something like:

 

`if($_POST['customer_submit']){
$user=$_POST['customer_login']['user'];
$pass=$_POST['customer_login']['pass'];
}else{
//admin submit button was clicked
$user=$_POST['admin_login']['user'];
$pass=$_POST['admin_login']['pass'];
}`

Answer (score 1):

Change the name attrbute in one of your forms and then on php side check which $_POST values you get. For example:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Sign in">

if($_POST['Submit2']){
  //form 2 has been sent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a post name with customer login only for the customer form.

```
if(isset($_POST['customer_login'])){
    $user=$_POST['customer_login']['user'];
    $pass=$_POST['customer_login']['pass'];
}else{
    //admin submit button was clicked
    $user=$_POST['admin_login']['user'];
    $pass=$_POST['admin_login']['pass'];
}
```